# Send array to php via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to send a JS array to a php file via ajax.

JS code:

```
$('#basket').on('click',function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "basket.php",
        data: {vektor: itemNameArray},
        success: function(){

            window.location.href ="basket.php";
            console.log(itemNameArray);

        }
    });

});
```

php code:

```
<?php
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: test 1');</script>");
    if(isset($_GET['vektor'])){
        echo("<script>console.log('PHP: test 2');</script>");
        $vektor = $_post['vektor'];
        echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$vektor."');</script>");
    }
```

But it seems that my get with key vektor is not working. I get in LOG my array and the first echo with test 1 but not second.
I need to send a array to php file to create a html code. That is becuse I need to open "basket.php" to see result.

Comment: you have $_post instead of $_GET here: `$vektor = $_post['vektor'];`. 2nd: You are redirecting straight after you receive an answer from php, yet not even take what php is sending back to ajax (in success function)

Comment: AJAX sends data in the background, and one usually processes the result in the success function. Your code looks like you want to simulate a form submission though, in which case AJAX is the wrong approach. What you need is `<form method="post" action="basket.php"><input name="vektor" type="hidden"></form>`; then you'll want to replace that AJAX call with 1. setting the value of the input to `JSON.stringify(itemNameArray)` and 2. calling `submit()` on the form.

Comment: @Jeff if I remove the first echo than will it working? I use POST before instead GET

Comment: No, because `window.location.href ="basket.php";` is a new GET request and will cause both `$_GET` and `$_POST` to be empty.

Comment: Before we waste any more time, please answer a simple question: When the user clicks on `#basket`, do you want to a) send data to the server *in the background* and remain on the current page **or** b) send the user over to `basket.php` where their current basket is listed? (doesn't matter what kind of element gets clicked)

Comment: @ChrisG the click function is on a <a> tag

Comment: @ChrisG I will send user to basket.php and my array to create html code in basket.php

Comment: then you don't need ajax at all, a form could be the right choice maybe (depends on where `itemNameArray` is coming from).

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. This means that you don't use AJAX for this. All you want to do is fake a form submission; and like I explained in my first comment, AJAX is the wrong approach for that. Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1ftb4y0a/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed GET and post to POST. You messed with POST and GET, that the first major mistake.

> But it seems that my **get** with key vektor is not working. I get in LOG
>   my array and the first echo with test 1 but not second **(post not POST)**. I need to send
>   a array to php file to create a html code.(for that type of data **POST** is preferable) That is because I need to
>   open "basket.php" to see result.

```
$('#basket').on('click',function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "basket.php",
                data: {vektor: itemNameArray},
                success: function(){

                    //window.location.href ="basket.php";
                    console.log(itemNameArray);

                }
            });

        });
```

php code:

```
<?php
echo("<script>console.log('PHP: test 1');</script>");
  if(isset($_POST['vektor'])){
     echo("<script>console.log('PHP: test 2');</script>");
     $vektor = $_POST['vektor'];
     echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$vektor."');</script>");
 }
```

Comment: The answer only addresses one of many issues. Also it would be helpfull to explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: I fix an answer. Fixed those errors I can see, there can be issues. And this looks like example of a code.